# How to keep old value in select option when updated the form in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to keep old value in select option when I updated the form?

Form:

```
<select class="form-select" name="slug" id="slug" value="{{$project->slug ?? '' }}">
<option value="">Select Category </option>
<option value="commercial">commercial</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `old()` like this

```
<select class="form-select" name="slug" id="slug">
    <option value="commercial" {{ old('slug', $project->slug) == 'commercial' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Commercial</option>
    <option value="another" {{ old('slug', $project->slug) == 'another' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Another</option>
    <option value="anotherrr" {{ old('slug', $project->slug) == 'anotherrr' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Anotherrr</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `@selected(bool)`, and if the condition is true it will return selected.

```html
<select class="form-select" name="slug" id="slug">
    <option value="commercial" @selected(old('slug', $project->slug) == 'commercial')>Commercial</option>
    <option value="another" @selected(old('slug', $project->slug) == 'another')>Another</option>
</select>
```